How to merge or get the latest version of the record synced to S3 bucket from CDC?
I have multiple systems/microservices which emits any change(CDC) to the records in Database as events. All these microservices' database tables have consumer id as key. These events(avro) then published to Kafka and then a consumer writes them to parquet files in AWS S3 with partition as the consumer id. For e.g
CS_12345/consumer.parquet
CS_12345/consumeremail.parquet
......
Now since all update/delete operations are captured which are sent as events and then stored as parquet files which are unique files, I want to know how can i merge the data in multiple files or create the latest record of a consumer as if I am querying the database(which contains the latest committed data)
Thanks in advance
